# Android request location permission causes alertdialog to display twice

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to display user current location when clicking a button using this code:

```
 mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String[] permissions;
                        permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, 4);
                        else {
                            mButton.setText("");
                            // request and display location
                        }
            }
        });
```

So far, so good, but when I am checking the permissions results (`onRequestPermissionsResult`) I am using a `for` statement to iterate the `permissions` array and inside I am creating a dialog to explain why the current permission is needed. The problem is - because the permissions needed are `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` the `for` statement runs twice, here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (requestCode == 4) {
                for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {
                    String permission = permissions[i];
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
                        if (!showRationale) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setMessage("The application must have permission to find location");
                            builder.setTitle("Location");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                                    intent.setData(uri);
                                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            });
                            builder.show();
                        } else if (Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.equals(permission) || Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.equals(permission)) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setMessage("The application must have permission to find location");
                            builder.setTitle("Location");
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    String[] permissionss = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionss, 4);
                                }
                            });
                            builder.show();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No permission to use location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
                    } else if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        // request and display location
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There are many solutions I thought of, passing only one permission in the permissions `String[]` array, showing the dialog with an `if` statement only `if(i==0)`. I don't know what is the correct solution for this problem. Thanks.

P.S - Sorry for my English.

**NEW FINAL WORKING CODE WITH LIBRARY:**

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        requestLocation();
                    else
                        MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.requestLocationWithCheck(MainActivity.this);
}
});

@NeedsPermission({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION})
    public void requestLocation() {
        double lo = 0.0, la = 0.0;
        removeItem();
        myToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lo + " , " + la, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        myToast.show();
        // Get Location And Display It Using Toast.
        showQuestion("Location");
    }

@OnNeverAskAgain({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION})
    void showNeverAskForLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_location_neverask, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("The application must have permission to find location");
        builder.setTitle("Location");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    @OnShowRationale({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION})
    void showRationaleForLocation(final PermissionRequest request) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("The application must have permission to find location");
        builder.setTitle("Location");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                request.proceed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                request.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
@OnPermissionDenied({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION})
    void showDeniedForLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_location_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: try https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher,PermissionsDispatcher provides a simple annotation-based API to handle runtime permissions

Comment: @darwin Thanks, I actually never knew about this and it can make every application I create much simpler.

Comment: @Darwin I can't ask here for permission_group.location and I still need to ask for both FINE_LOCATION and COURSE_LOCATION so issue still exists.

Comment: @Darwin - Fixed, sorry to interrupt too much.